# How to find out if the three $3\times1$ vectors are a basis for $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}7\\0\\-5\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-5\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know that they are not linearly independent because they vectors are not multiples of each other. With that being said, since they are not linearly independent, I do not know how to further test to see if they are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Use row-reduction (Gauß' pivot method).

Comment: I have done that, after I have obtained a RREF form of the vectors, what then do I do to tell if its a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: If the matrix  in reduced form has $3$ non-zero rows, it's a basis. The number of non-zero rows is the rank of the system of vectors, i.e. the dimension of their span.

Comment: when you say non-zero row, do you mean that [1,0,0] could be a non zero row, or do you mean that each element in the row must be a non -zero? Such as [1,1,1]

Comment: @Yusha nonzero row means at least one element is not zero, i.e. a zero row is a row of all zeroes.

Comment: So then that means that these are a basis! I got $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Your title currently says "two 3x1 vectors" even though there are three of them.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Fixed

Comment: Reading "I know that they are not linearly independent because they vectors are not multiples of each other" I wonder whether that was a misprint or you really do not understand.  If the vectors **were** "multiples of each other" then the would be **dependent**.  But the fact that they are *not* multiples of each other does *not* prove they are not *dependent*.   (If your really knew they were **not independent** that would immediately  prove they were not a basis!)

Comment: Yes, they are not Linearly indepedent. @user247327

Answer (score 3):

**Definition:** A set of vectors $\{\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_k\}\subset \Bbb R^n$ is *linearly independent* if $$\lambda_1\mathbf v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k\mathbf v_k = \mathbf 0 \implies \lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_k=0$$

where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k \in \Bbb R$.  If a set of vectors is not linearly independent, it is *linearly dependent*.

**Definition:** A set $\{\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_k\}\subset \Bbb R^n$ is a *basis* if it is a linearly independent spanning set.

---

So for your set of vectors, we know there are the right number for a basis (because the dimension of $\Bbb R^3$ is $3$), so we just need to see if they are linearly independent.

$$\lambda_1 (1,1,-2) + \lambda_2 (7,0,-5) + \lambda_3 (-5,-1,2) = (0,0,0) \iff \pmatrix{1 & 7 & -5 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -2 & -5 & 2}\pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

Solve this system of equations and if the only solution is $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ then your set is a linearly independent set.  If there are **any other solutions** then your set is linearly dependent and thus not a basis.

Comment: So then that means that these are a basis! I got $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: OK.  If you row reduced and got that then $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ so this is indeed a basis.

Comment: @Yusha Just a note: You can see from the definition of linear independence that it has nothing to do with where the vectors are multiples of each other -- unless there happen to be only two vectors in your set.  So don't think you can tell just be looking at whether the vectors are multiples of each other.